# Java codes to run program from detected drive

Tags: java, batch-file, removable-storage

I have a program that I want to run from a detected USB drive (removable storage such as a USB), and this was done by creating two classes: external.java and DetectDrive.java as follows:

external.java

```
 public class external
 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException  
    {

    DetectDrive d = new DetectDrive();
    String DetectDrive = d.USBDetect();
    BufferedWriter fileOut;
    String filePath = DetectDrive;
    System.out.println(filePath);

    try 
        {
        fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("F:\\external.bat"));
        fileOut.write("cd "+ filePath +"\n");
        fileOut.write("external.exe"+"\n");

        fileOut.close(); //close the output stream after all output is done
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = rt.exec("cmd /c start" +DetectDrive+ "\\external.bat");
        p.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }       
    }
}
```

DetectDrive.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class DetectDrive
{
    public String USBDetect()
    {
        String driveLetter = "";
        FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();

        File[] f = File.listRoots();
        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
        {
            String drive = f[i].getPath();
            String displayName = fsv.getSystemDisplayName(f[i]);
            String type = fsv.getSystemTypeDescription(f[i]);
            boolean isDrive = fsv.isDrive(f[i]);
            boolean isFloppy = fsv.isFloppyDrive(f[i]);
            boolean canRead = f[i].canRead();
            boolean canWrite = f[i].canWrite();

            if (canRead && canWrite && !isFloppy && isDrive && (type.toLowerCase().contains("removable") || type.toLowerCase().contains("rimovibile")))
            {
                //log.info("Detected PEN Drive: " + drive + " - "+ displayName); 
                driveLetter = drive;
                break;
            }
        }

        /*if (driveLetter.equals(""))
        {
            System.out.println("Not found!");
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println(driveLetter);
        }
        */

        //System.out.println(driveLetter);
        return driveLetter;
    }
}
```

The problem now is that there are no errors when I run the external.java (main). However, the output only shows the detected drive which is F:\ but it doesn’t run the specified program which is external.exe and it also mentioned that the program got terminated. Can someone please help me point out where I went wrong and what the correct codes should be like? I am new to Java.

I got the DetectDrive codes from http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/506/Detect-USB-removable-drive-in-Java which I believe is now in maintenance.

**Is it possible to change the new FileWriter("*F:\external.bat*") to detect the USB drive directory instead? For example letting the program detect the usb drive and automatically put in the correct directory instead of us typing the F:\ manually. I have no answer for this yet. Please help!**

Comment: First thing to check would be user rights. Have you tried with switched-off UAC?

Comment: I have tried switching it off and it still says terminated. Do you know how I can run that in virtual machine?

Comment: `cd x:\yyy\zzz` needs to be done in two commands: `x:` and `cd \yyy\zzz`.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how I can do it in two commands? Is it the one under the fileOut?

Comment: try reading Process's error stream and output stream for possible issues

Comment: `"x:\r\ncd yyy/zzz\r\n"`. With a carriage-return + linefeed for line separator.

Comment: I found my mistake already. Thanks for taking the time to help me though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems problem is with command :

```
"cmd /c start" +DetectDrive+ "\\external.bat"
```

It should have a `{space}` after start:

```
"cmd /c start " +DetectDrive+ "\\external.bat"
```

Comment: what is the output from `System.out.println(filePath);`

Comment: Thanks! It worked! However, do you know how I can run this in virtual machine?

Comment: It says F:\ I think I realised my mistake. I changed the fileOut.write("cd "+ filePath +"\n") to just fileOut.write(filePath) and it changed the directory to my usb.

Comment: Do you know how I can run it in virtual machine? I think the program doesn't work in the host machine so I'm trying to test it in vm but I don't really know how.